# Connecting JetBrains DataGrip to Google BigQuery - Error in connection

Tags: google-bigquery, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I am trying to connect DataGrip to Google BigQuery exactly following the steps on the JetBrains blog (https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2018/07/10/using-bigquery-from-intellij-based-ide/) but I keep getting the same error message when I test the connection:

> The specified database user/password combination is rejected: com.simba.googlebigquery.support.exceptions.GeneralException: EXEC_JOB_EXECUTION_ERR

And on that same pop up box, it is asking me to enter my login credentials for BigQuery. I shouldn't need to do this as I created a service account in GCP with the correct level of access, and used the json key stored on my local machine (and linked to this service account).

Any ideas?

Expected result: Successful connection
Actual result: Error message above

Comment: What JDBC driver do you use?

Comment: I use the simba JDBC drivers (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/providers/simba-drivers/), the JDBC 4.2-compatible files. When configuring the BigQuery connection, I selected all the .jar files from the simba zip file

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: @RazvanCristianLung
I use the following jdbc url to connect to BigQuery using service account: `jdbc:bigquery://https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2:443;ProjectId=${PROJECT_ID};OAuthType=0;OAuthServiceAcctEmail=${SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL};OAuthPvtKeyPath=${FULL_PATH_TO_SERVICE_ACC_KEY_FILE};`

Comment: are you able to write from DataGrip to BigQuery? I get "[HYC00][10220] [Simba][JDBC](10220) Driver does not support this optional feature."

Comment: @kekchoze  do you still experience the issue?

Comment: No, all worked out in the end. You can download a Simba JDBC driver on the Google Cloud BigQuery Partners' page. There's also a blog article on the Jetbrains blog dated 10 Oct 2018 which explains what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Since DataGrip 2021.1 BigQuery is fully supported and issues with Google Service Account authentication are gone.

[image: Google Service Account]